# change the saved path of huge number of xref in different files in Autocad 2010

Tags: autocad

I am using Autocad 2010 and I have transfered
the data base to another location, but all the xref
stayed at the same place: D:\profiles\sources\,
now the xref manager shows that all the files attached
to some file are not found.
How do I change the save path of all the xref to:
G:\database\profiles\sources\
It
Thanks.

Comment: are you talking about writing a script or program? What language(s) do you know?

Comment: unfortunatly I don't know any scripting programs.  I know JAVA and c/c++

Answer (score 0):

Following up on your comment on knowing C++, the Main API for AutoCAD, called ARX, is C++. Start here: http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=1911627 for an overview and have a look at the links on [Developing plugins for AutoCAD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091778/developing-plugins-for-autocad)